# how to retrieve the data from go api using ajax?

Tags: ajax, go

I'm retrieving the data using ajax from golang api but in ajax success function the response is not returning the user data while golang will returning it.
Below is the ajax I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"/api/v1/customer/:id",
        type: "GET",
        success: function(results){
            console.log(results) //it will not retrieving the data
        }
    });
});
```

Output of ajax

```
//nothing
```

here is the golang router:

```
Route{"GetFullCustomer", "GET", "/customer/:id", controller.GetCustomer}
// when I will hit this url then the function GetCustomer will run.
v1 := router.Group("/api/v1") // there is also grouping
```

Here is the function which is retrieving the user:

```
func GetCustomer(c *gin.Context) {
  t, _ := template.ParseFiles("index.html")
  t.Execute(c.Writer, nil)
  customerIdString := c.Param("id")  //taking the id from url
  customerId, err := strconv.Atoi(customerIdString)
  mongoSession := config.ConnectDb()
  collection := mongoSession.DB("customer").C("customercollection")
  pipeline := []bson.M{
    bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"_id": customerId}},
    bson.M{"$lookup": bson.M{"from" : "address", "localField" : "_id", "foreignField": "user_id","as": "address" }},
    // bson.M{"$project":bson.M{"_id":0}}
  }
  pipe := collection.Pipe(pipeline)
  resp := []bson.M{}
  err = pipe.All(&resp)
  if err != nil {
     fmt.Println("Errored: %#v \n", err)
  }
 c.JSON(200, gin.H{"data": resp})
}
```

by hitting the url of localhost `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/customer/1` Output of terminal is:

```
[GIN] 2018/05/04 - 12:40:11 | 200 |   11.200709ms |             ::1 | GET      /api/v1/customer/1
[map[$match:map[_id:0]] map[$lookup:map[from:address localField:_id foreignField:user_id as:address]]]
[]
[GIN] 2018/05/04 - 12:40:11 | 200 |    6.986699ms |             ::1 | GET      /api/v1/customer/Person.png
[map[$match:map[_id:0]] map[$lookup:map[foreignField:user_id as:address from:address localField:_id]]]
[]
[GIN] 2018/05/04 - 12:40:12 | 200 |    1.619845ms |             ::1 | GET      /api/v1/customer/:id
```

Issue is that while golang url hit show above the golang will take the `/:id` dynamically and matches the data but the ajax don't take this id dynamically. So how I will resolve my problem.

Comment: remove `datatype:"json"` in your ajax code to see the result and post here

Comment: okay see when i run the `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/customer/1` this url `1` is dynamically id of the user it retrieve nothing and on go code in terminal it gives me output as `[map[$match:map[_id:0]] map[$lookup:map[from:address localField:_id foreignField:user_id as:address]]]` @Himanshu and i removed the `datatype:"json"`

Comment: no I am saying in ajax remove `datatype:"json"`. In go code the output you are showing is your final output when writing to response.

Comment: in response it will show me the html document

Comment: you see you are returning html that's why the error and I have asked you to remove `datatype:"json"`. So that you can receiv any type retuning from golang

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170342/discussion-between-gourav-and-himanshu).

Comment: @gourav Your `GetCustomer` handler still executes the html template, why? The otuput shows the contents of the `pipeline` variable, this suggests that you're passing the wrong variable to `c.JSON`. Please provide the exact code that you're executing in your Go program, how else do you expect us to help you if what you show us is not the actual code you're running?

Comment: @gourav as far as javascript is concerned, you can just append the id of the customer you want to retrieve to the endpoint path. `var id = 1;` and then `var path = "/api/v1/customer/" + id;` and then use `path` as the `url` value of the ajax request. Refactoring that into a function should be easy enough I hope.

Comment: @mkopriva yeah as you say i will append the id with the url but now the problem is that ajax will not retrieving any type of data.

Comment: @Himanshu are you there

Comment: @gourav without sharing the exact code you're running, client-side as well as server-side, and without sharing the output and errors if any, I don't know how to help.

Comment: join the chat room please. see the code i will give there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170352/discussion-between-gourav-and-mkopriva).

Comment: can we `static` function for this @Himanshu ? if yes can you tell me how?

Comment: @gourav can you explain what static function you are talking about

Comment: @Himanshu see this example https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/issues/75 and this too https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#RouterGroup.StaticFile

Comment: If you wants to serve static files on `/` path. you can create a middleware just like express do. And use that middlleware to serve static files.

Comment: means html like that?? its CROS middlleware ? @Himanshu

Comment: What you wants to achieve is to serve static files using gin on root path ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170536/discussion-between-gourav-and-himanshu).

Comment: @Himanshu can you please do short discussion on it

Answer (score 2):

It may be silently failing. You need to check the Developer Tools in your browser. In Chrome there is a Network tab which shows info about each AJAX request. It is likely that the AJAX call is failing for some reason and you need to get find out what the error is. You'll probably see it in the Console tab as well.

Also, just noticed that dataType is set to "html", which seems incorrect based on the output format you described. It should probably be "json".

You should handle failures in your AJAX requests so that the user knows there is a problem. Here is some code to get you started:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var promise = $.ajax({
        url:"/api/v1/customer/:id",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json'
    });

    promise.done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });

    promise.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("Request failed. jqXHR.status=" + jqXHR.status + ", textStatus=" + textStatus + ", errorThrown=" + errorThrown);
    });
});
```

Comment: hi, using your code not it will show me `Request failed. jqXHR.status=200, textStatus=parsererror, errorThrown=SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` this? what it means??

Comment: Yes this is the error. It sounds like the response is in an invalid format. This is likely a problem with the Golang code. You can open the Developer Tools, go to the Network tab, and view what response is being returned from the Golang call. The '<' character in the response is causing the JSON parsing to fail.

Comment: you are saying the data i am retrieving that is not in json format, right?

Comment: Can't say for sure until you view the response in the Developer Tools. It may be a JSON response that is invalid.

Comment: @gourav your Go code is returning index html page. You're executing the template `index.html` with `c.Writer` as its first argument. `fmt.Printf("%s\n", b)` does not magically send the json response to the client, that just prints it to std out.

Comment: @gourav Something like this https://play.golang.org/p/HhcBffEyLSJ I'm not familiar with mongo nor gin so there may be errors there.

Comment: yeah i'm also using `c.JSON(200, gin.H{"data": b})` this one but  ajax still goes on failure. :(

Comment: @gourav `c.JSON` does json marshaling for you, it also sets the necessary headers. Don't marshal `resp` yourself and then pass `b` into `c.JSON`, pass in `resp` directly into `c.JSON`. E.g. `c.JSON(200, gin.H{"data": resp})`

Comment: i just follow you but not getting the data

Comment: @gourav update your question adding the updated code you're using and also add the error you're getting.